# gcc gives weird Intel syntax

Tags: assembly, gcc, disassembly, intel-syntax

I have been trying to get a better idea of what happens under the hood by using the compiler to generate the assembly programs of various C programs at different optimization levels. There is something that has been bothering me for a while.

When I compile `t.c` as follows,

```
gcc -S t.c
```

I get the assembly in AT&T syntax as follows.

```
function:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    addl    8(%ebp), %eax
    popl    %ebp
    ret
    .size   function, .-function
```

When I compile using the masm argument as follows:-

```
gcc -S t.c -masm=intel
```

I get the following output.

```
function:
    push    %ebp
    mov %ebp, %esp
    mov %eax, DWORD PTR [%ebp+12]
    add %eax, DWORD PTR [%ebp+8]
    pop %ebp
    ret
    .size   function, .-function
```

There is a change in syntax but there are still "%"s before the notation of registers(this is why I don't prefer AT&T syntax in the first place).

Can someone shed some light on why this is happening? How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GNU assembler (gas) does have a separate option for controlling the % prefix. Documentation seems to suggest GCC doesn't have such an option, but my GCC (version Debian 4.3.2-1.1) doesn't produce the % prefix.

Comment: Indeed, GCC4.1 on Godbolt shows what the OP was seeing, asm for `.intel_syntax prefix`.  Newer GCC makes proper Intel-syntax asm for `.intel_syntax noprefix`.  https://godbolt.org/z/sWcjqGGaK  . (GCC 4.1 actually uses the directive `.intel_syntax`, and `prefix` is the default for both it and `.att_syntax`, unfortunately.  Never use `.intel_syntax prefix` or `.att_syntax noprefix`, confusing hybrid abominations.)

Comment: And BTW, GCC doesn't use command-line options for putting GAS into Intel or AT&T mode, but the relevant options are `-msyntax=ATT` or `-msyntax=INTEL` and `-mnaked-reg` (noprefix)  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dOptions.html

Answer (score -1):

I think you excepted to get intel syntex while disassemble, I'm not sure but try this following steps,

1. gcc <filename.c>
2. gdb ./a.out
3. set disassembly intel
4. disassemble main

[Refer this image, which i shared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz9UO.png)

Comment: Please [don't post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Instead, include them as text.

Comment: You could just as easily have used `gcc -S -masm=intel`; with GCC newer than 4.1, it makes normal Intel syntax (`.intel_syntax noprefix`).  What the OP's seeing, `.intel_syntax prefix` with basically Intel syntax but still decorating registers with `%`, hasn't been a problem since GCC 4.1.  Disassembling into Intel syntax always works, but loses label names and other symbolic stuff from the compiler's asm output, just becoming numbers in the linked executable.